# Priority queue to push pair and int

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I want to use `priority_queue` like this:

```
priority_queue< pair< int, int> ,int ,cmp >
```

The comparision should be based on the `int` value in non-decreasing order.

Example:

```
((2,5),1),((2,5),2),((2,5),3)
```

Comment: You can't use `priority_queue` like that. You need to reconsider your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Read the template parameters of [std::priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) again. The second parameter is the underlying container. You can't use an `int`.

What you seem to be asking is how to store a `pair` and an `int` in a priority queue and sort by the `int`. Well, you've already figured out how to store a `pair` of ints. Simply expand that idea and store a `pair`of a `pair` and `int`. That's a naïve solution though. Instead, I recommend using a `struct` with the `pair` and the `int` as members so that you can give them descriptive names. Consider using a `struct` for the `pair` of ints too. Then simply use a compare functor which compares the third `int` only in the order of your choosing ignoring the `pair`.

Answer (score 0):

priority_queue accepts only "one element" by saying one element I mean only a single element of arbitrary type. For having a pair, and int and another component in the priority queue you need to bring all of them as one meaning you need to be build a struct which will hold them. Then you have to use the bool operator < to tell the compiler how to compare the elements of your type .

```
    bool operator < ( const structName& left, const structName& right)
{
     return left.number < right. number;
}
```

this means that the comparison must be done with the member named number.